# Problems after upgrading from Python 3.5 to Python 3.6 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, installation, pip

I followed this [Medium article](https://medium.com/@moreless/install-python-3-6-on-ubuntu-16-04-28791d5c2167) to upgrade Python 3.5 (to be specific, Python 3.5.2) to 3.6 (to be specific, Python 3.6.3) in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

In that article, I had **skipped** the first step which is ...

> **Login via SSH and update all installed packages** 
> First of all, login to your Ubuntu 16.04 VPS via SSH as user root 
> `ssh root@IP_Address -p Port_number` 
> and update all installed packages

I followed the remaining steps and between step 4 (Method 1) & step 5 (Method 2), I had chosen step 4 (Method 1). During all the steps, I didn't get even a single error. Now, in general, I'm not having any side-effects in my machine but from a Python perspective, I'm having the following issues:

1. Python 3.5.2 is still there in my machine: if I type `Python3` then 3.6.3 gets opened but if I type `Python3.5` then 3.5.2 gets opened up. So, even after upgrading, is it normal to have Python 3.5.2 in my machine?
2. I can't install any Python package/library using `pip3` because it still points to Python 3.5.2 only.
3. When I open Jupyter notebook, it's still pointing to Python 3.5.2 (I'm not using `virtualenv`) How can I point it to Python 3.6.3?

#### Additional Info:

1. Here is the output of some commands:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.12

$ python3 -V
Python 3.6.3

$ python3.5 -V
Python 3.5.2

$ which python
/usr/bin/python

$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

$ which python3.5
/usr/bin/python3.5
```

2. When I try to `import` some libraries using `Python3.5` (pointing to 3.5.2) v/s `Python3` (pointing to 3.6.3)

```
$ python3.5
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul 17 2020, 14:04:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> 

$ python3
Python 3.6.3 (default, Jul 15 2020, 20:42:43) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
>>>
```

3. `pip` versions:

```
$ pip2 -V
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

$ pip -V
pip 20.1.1 from /home/milan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)

$ pip3 -V
pip 20.1.1 from /home/milan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

So, running `pip3 install numpy` installs `numpy` for Python 3.5.2 not for Python 3.6.3

4. As typing `Python3` open Python 3.6.3, so I even tried `$ python3 -m pip install numpy` command to install package e.g. `numpy` for my Python 3.6.3 but got the following error(s):

```
Collecting numpy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/e7/4b2bdddb99f5f631d8c1de259897c2b7d65dcfcc1e0a6fd17a7f62923500/numpy-1.19.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (13.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 13.4MB 124kB/s 
Installing collected packages: numpy
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy'
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 20.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

So, now, how can I install packages/libraries for Python 3.6.3 in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS? Is it even possible?

How can I point my Jupyter Notebook to point to Python 3.6.3 without installing `virtualenv`? Currently, here is the output from my Jupyter Notebook which is very confusing:

```
1.  from platform import python_version
2.  print(python_version())

3.5.2

1.  !python3 -V

Python 3.6.3
```

Also, after seeing the above outputs for different commands, is my system messed up now (I mean from a system point of view)? Do I have to reinstall my Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: try updating the pip from 3.6, maybe it could help: `python3 -m pip install -U pip`

Answer (score 1):

1. After updating binaries you should run to refresh your cache with the newest versions of your binaries (python3.6 instead of python3.5!)

```
sudo ldconfig
```

2. After that, run

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

to ensure correct pip version for your new python binary.

No, your system is not messed up and you do NOT have to reinstall Ubuntu.

greetings